# How to include C-runtime functions in Delphi component

Tags: c++, c, delphi, c++builder

I am using C++Builder XE2. In my project I use a mix of C++ and Delphi components, which so far has worked great.

I use one particular Delphi component - TATViewer, which is an image viewer. The Delphi files are included in a C++Builder .cbproj project and compile and install just fine.

The component can be extended with JPEG 2000 support by using JasPer JPEG 2000 library, which is written in C, but has a fine Delphi wrapper (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pasjas/). The Delphi wrapper is a single Delphi unit that links in the C .obj files.

Everything compiles, but during linking I run into problems: It cannot find the C library functions used by the JasPer library:

```
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'strchr' referenced from C:\COMPONENTS\BCBXE2\ATVIEWER\CBUILDER\JP2IMG.OBJ
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'atol' referenced from C:\COMPONENTS\BCBXE2\ATVIEWER\CBUILDER\JP2IMG.OBJ
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'wcscpy' referenced from C:\COMPONENTS\BCBXE2\ATVIEWER\CBUILDER\JP2IMG.OBJ
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'abort' referenced from C:\COMPONENTS\BCBXE2\ATVIEWER\CBUILDER\JP2IMG.OBJ
```

The Delphi unit uses the crtl library which is a wrapper around most C libraries, and declares the functions not included in crtl itself:

```
const
  msvcrtdll = 'msvcrt.dll';
//referenced functions, not declared in delphi crtl unit

procedure __assert; external msvcrtdll name '_assert';
procedure _atexit; external msvcrtdll name 'atexit';
procedure _abort; external msvcrtdll name 'abort';
procedure _strrchr; external msvcrtdll name 'strrchr';
```

How do I get this C++Builder project with Delphi units using C functions to link? I'm sure I must be missing something simple.

Comment: In your scenario, you don't want to link against msvcrt because your C++ Builder executable has a perfectly good C runtime. So I'd guess you need to remove the `uses crtl` and find a way to link against the C++Builder runtime

Comment: David, the problem is that the JasPer wrapper unit is compiled as a stand-alone unit, so it errors out if crtl is not in the Uses clause. I then get lots of "Error: E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration".

Comment: How are you linking to your C++ runtime? Statically or dynamically. If the latter then it's easy enough. You just supply `external` declarations in the same way as found in `crtl`, but using the C++ Builder runtime DLL. Harder with static runtime linking I guess. Can a Delphi unit use a C++ Builder unit?

Comment: You might find [this link about using C object files in Delphi](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cobjs.html) very useful. In it it shows implementing some C-obj-required C-RTL functions in Delphi, examples being _malloc and some string functions - just like the ones you need.

Comment: Actually - if it compiles and installs fine (which includes linking!), what's different when linking your project? That would be a good first place to look.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I'm linking statically. And no, Delphi units cannot use a C++Builder unit except by linking in object files - AFAIK.

Comment: @DavidM What's different is the use of C++ Builder.

Comment: @DavidM: The Delphi unit builds and links in the .obj files fine. When I use it in a C++Builder package containing other Delphi files, it complains about the missing C functions.

Comment: @Sharkie I'm out of my depth here. I know plenty about linking C objects to Delphi units, but the added twist of C++ Builder takes me out of my zone of experience. Sorry I cannot help.

Comment: Latest thing I tried was to dump the C++Builder package and use a Delphi package. I can do this because XE2 includes both Delphi and C++Builder personalities (C++Builder didn't include the Delphi one before so you couldn't install pure Delphi components without creating a new C++Builder package). The component builds just fine! So this is one step further. However, when the C++ Builder project that uses the component links - it now fails here: e.g. "[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'atol' referenced from C:\COMPONENTS\BCBXE2\LIB\ATVIEWERD2009.LIB|jp2img". sigh...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thanks for trying, much appreciated. I now also tried getting rid of the crtl unit, adding all used C functions as externals. Same problem (had hoped using crtl in a component used in C++Builder was the cause - apparently not).

Comment: So... you have Delphi code in a Delphi-only BPL linking to a .obj file which requires specific functions to link, and this builds and links fine in Delphi.  When you use the already-built BPL in C++Builder, it doesn't link, complaining about missing methods. Is that a good summary? And, using the link I provided about manually providing the missing exports doesn't help? (That's my best guess, and do try that for every method it needs - it didn't work for atol?) In that case, I'm stumped. I'd suggest asking on the C++ Builder forums or opening a support ticket.

Comment: What does Dependency Viewer say for your successfully-compiled-and-installed Delphi BPL file?  A BPL is a DLL by another name.  Does it have any C++ RTL dependencies?  And does the BPL work when used in a Delphi project, ie you can create a new test Delphi project, use the component in it, and it all works fine? And the equivalent for a new C++ Builder project fails as above, missing methods?

Comment: What happens if you dynamically link to the BPL instead of statically?  Since it works (presumably) for Delphi as is, that might help...!

Comment: I have given up getting it to work. I'll await ImageEn updating the version of the JasPer library they include in their component and use that. Too much time wasted already.